# Jasmine - how to test confirm navigation?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I have an event listener for `onbeforeunload` that looks like this:

```
function(e) {
  return "Are you sure you don't want to continue?";
}
```

It works like a charm, but I can't figure out how to test in Jasmine. I would expect the following to provide a user affirmation, but it does not.

```
spyOn(window, 'confirm').andReturn(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are spying on `window.confirm` but that is not what is actually being called. You should spy on `window.onbeforeunload` to make sure that is being called and return true from that.

```
spyOn(window, "onbeforeunload").andReturn(true);
```